# Eigen matrix template alias

Tags: c++, eigen3

I had a class definition that compile with VS C++ 20 and not with g++-11
It just consist in an overload of the Eigen Matrix class to define a Vector type.

with g++ the compiler says:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 3)
using BaseVector = Eigen::Matrix< typename T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::StorageOptions::AutoAlign, Eigen::Dynamic, 1 >;
```

while compiling the following, and it put the error mark just before the last **>**:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector : public Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::StorageOptions::AutoAlign>
{
  public:
    using BaseVector = Eigen::Matrix< typename T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::StorageOptions::AutoAlign, Eigen::Dynamic, 1 >;

  ......etc.....
```

any idea will be welcome, to explain that compiler error, I already try typedef i.s.o the using (alias) but it's coming from something else !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a combination of MSVC accepting `typename` in a place where it does not belong and gcc producing a rather confusing error message. `1, should be at least 3` ?!? Probably it gets stuck at `typename T`, stops there and reports the wrong error.

Remove `typename` (`T` is not a [dependant name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)):

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"

template<typename T>
class Vector : public Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::StorageOptions::AutoAlign>
{
  public:
    using BaseVector = Eigen::Matrix<T, Eigen::Dynamic, 1, Eigen::StorageOptions::AutoAlign, Eigen::Dynamic, 1 >;
};
```

[Live gcc11](https://godbolt.org/z/Ks4b88oP9)